# Download all chat history in a discord server as TXT including emdeds

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to save all messages especially embeds in discord using a python bot.
I have managed to do chat history but it does not include the actual content of embeds

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    filename = f"{ctx.channel.name}.txt"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=None):
            file.write(f"{msg.created_at} - {msg.author.display_name}: {msg.clean_content}\n")
```

Can anyone help me? It must be a txt file

Comment: You can access embeds using `message.embeds` (which is a list of `discord.Embed` instances). Then, you can just print out the attributes of that embed however you like. Do note that storing messages for more than 30 days is against Discord's TOS.

Comment: Yeah I'll be honest I have no idea how to do that

Comment: What specific part do you find difficult about it? You're accessing a lot of attributes of classes in this code example here so you should know how to do it. There's not much else to it. The title of an embed is stored in `embed.title`, the fields are in `embed.fields`, etc. You don't have to do anything special, it's just a class with some attributes. The docs lists all fields of the `discord.Embed` class.